# How to add local files in Android.mk that are not located inside jni folder

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I'm getting an error about my AppDelegate cannot be found.
"The error is something like: No rule to make target *.cpp needed by *.o"

My Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes
```

I don't know what's wrong. I'm guessing it's because i'm not setting the path to the Classes right. In the package explorer my structure looks like this:
[image: screenshot of package explorer]

In my real folder structure, the Classes folder is not inside proj.android. It's in a folder located outside.

[image: Folders for Classes and MobileApp] Folders for Classes and MobileApp 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[image: Inside MobileApp] Inside MobileApp 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[image: Inside proj.android where jni is located]
Inside proj.android where jni is located

I'm not really sure how i to link my .ccp class files properly. How do I add them as my local files so  I can build it properly? I would appreciate all the help I could get. Thanks.

Comment: `AppDelegate.o` is already existed. Clean or delete `proj.android/obj` before you build it.

Comment: What if you use `$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp` ?

Comment: @Michael i tried this ../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp
it worked. but the problem is i had to type my classes one by one. Is there an easier way?

Comment: `$(wildcard ../../../Classes/*.cpp)`

Comment: `wildcard` cannot handle `../../../Classes/<sub dir>/*.cpp`. In that case, you can use the [recursive wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make/18258352#18258352) provided by @larskholte. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348969/android-mk-build-all-source-file-in-a-directory/25524275#25524275) is an example used in cocos2d-x project.

Comment: @GaloisPlusPlus thank you but the files are not inside LOCAL_PATH/x/x. The files are located outside in another directory. I found this from the answer:

rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))
SRC_PATH_CLASSES := $(call rwildcard, ../../Classes/, *.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(SRC_PATH_CLASSES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

Sorry I don't know much about these things.

Comment: @GaloisPlusPlus does ../ means move up like go to parent directory?

Comment: @cessmestreet Yes. In your case, you can replace the `SRC_PATH_CLASSES` with `SRC_PATH_CLASSES := $(call rwildcard, ../../../Classes/, *.cpp) `.

Comment: @cessmestreet Another tips. If you are not sure whether `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` is correctly set or not, you can use `$(warning $(VAR))` to print related variables like `LOCAL_PATH`, `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's a little hard to tell from your screenshots, but it looks like the Classes and jni directories are in the same parent directory. If that's true, you only need one '../' to go back up to the parent directory. Basically, I think you want to change all your paths to Classes to '../Classes/'. It looks like the path to cocos2d should be changed the same way.

Also, you're missing the last line of a module, which would be include $(). For example, if you want to build a dynamically linked library for your C++ code, you should add this line to the end of Android.mk:

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You can see some example Android.mks [here](http://android.mk), and the relevant Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html).